# Displaying all stack history of a process

Tags: solaris-10, dbx, pstack

How can i display all function calls of a process on Solaris?

dbx and pstack prints the call stack. What I want is a list of all the functions called by the process. In other words the output of several pstacks of the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see all the function calls a process makes, as it makes them, using [truss](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/816-5165/truss-1.html) with the `-u` option.

```
truss -u a.out -u : yourprogram args ...
```

will show all the calls made to functions in your program and to functions in libraries such as libc.

```
truss -u a.out -u :: yourprogram args ...
```

will also trace calls from library functions to other library functions. It'll be a lot more output; a call to `printf` will result in dozens of other calls to C library functions.